# Getting elements using multiple tags

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I wish to pull data into excel from the following link: https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/13817/7/1 for Tox summaries for inhalation routes, dermal, eyes etc

The code below partly achieves this

```
Public Sub GetContents3()

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/13817/7/1", False
XMLReq.send
                    
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementById("SectionContent")

Debug.Print SubSectList.innerText


End Sub
```

Although the code above works okay there are a few issues Id like to address.

For some reason the first  `Workers - Hazard via inhalation route is not being pulled`.

I wish to use the tags `dt` and `dd` to refine how the information should be pulled. As an example of how I would like the data to be printed:

```
Workers - Hazard via inhalation route    
Systemic effects
Long term exposure
Hazard assessment conclusion: DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
Value: 1.41 mg/m³
... Etc (to include all data) 

Workers - Hazard via dermal route
Systemic effects
Long term exposure
Hazard assessment conclusion: DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
Value: 2.06 mg/kg bw/day

And So on for each Route.
```

To try and Achieve this I have the following code:

```
Public Sub GetContents3()
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/13817/7/1", False
    XMLReq.send
                        
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    
    Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementById("SectionContent")
    Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")
    
    For Each SubSect In SubSects
    Debug.Print SubSect.innerText & " " & SubSect.NextSibling.innerText
    Next SubSect
    
End Sub
```

This is better but now it doesn't pull the subheadings.

I need someway to pull the information from multiple tags without overlapping data however I am unsure how to do this and so far attempts have just caused errors.

If anyone knows how I can modify the code to achieve the desired output above that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a css selector pattern to match the relevant tags, then during a loop over returned nodes, check the tagName, if DD or DT you need to combine into a single line for output:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetContents()

    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/13817/7/1", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim nodeList As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, i As Long, r As Long, concat As String
    
    Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#SectionContent h3,#SectionContent h4,#SectionContent h5,#SectionContent h6, #SectionContent  dt, #SectionContent dd")
 
    For i = 1 To nodeList.Length - 1
         
         Select Case nodeList.Item(i).tagName
            Case "DT"
               concat = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
            Case "DD"
                concat = concat & Chr$(32) & nodeList.Item(i).innerText
                r = r + 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = concat
            Case Else
                concat = vbNullString
                r = r + 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
        
        End Select
    Next
    
End Sub
```

---

Now, I would like something tidier than the requested list, so how about the following tabulation?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetContents()

    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/13817/7/1", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim nodeList As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, i As Long
    Dim c As Long, r As Long, tag As String
    
    Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#SectionContent h3,#SectionContent h4,#SectionContent h5,#SectionContent h6, #SectionContent  dt, #SectionContent dd")
    r = 1
    
    For i = 1 To nodeList.Length - 1
         
         tag = nodeList.Item(i).tagName
         
         Select Case tag
            Case "DT"
               c = 5  
            Case "DD"
               c = 6
               r = r + 1
            Case Else
               c = Right$(tag, 1) - 2
        End Select
        ActiveSheet.Cells(IIf(tag = "DD", r - 1, r), c) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
    Next
    
End Sub
```